# How to convert a CSV file to single JSON-serializable variables?

Tags: zapier

In order to automate our reporting, we want to convert Google Sheets cells to dynamic fields that we can use in a pre-written text. We think this is possible with Zapier.

We currently have the following code:

```py
import csv
import requests

from csv import reader

result = []

url = input_data['csvlink']

stats = requests.get(url)
content = stats.content.decode('iso-8859-1')

for line in csv.reader(content.splitlines()):
    result.append(line)

values = { i : result[i] for i in range(0, len(result) ) }

return values
```

However, this code returns a dictionary with the CSV row numbers as keys, and the data of the entire corresponding row as its value.

How can we return a dictionary with a key for every unique data point in the CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

This is another case of the computer correctly doing exactly what you told it to. Namely in:

```py
values = { i : result[i] for i in range(0, len(result) ) }
```

You say that `values` should be an dict where each key is a number and the value is the csv line at that index in the results.

In the comments, you mentioned wanting the entire CSV. Try something like:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase

result = {}
# your CSV code goes here. The data should be in `lines`, not `result`

for num_row, line in enumerate(lines):
    for num_column, col in enumerate(line):
        result[ascii_uppercase[num_column] + str(num_row + 1)] = col

return result
```

This will work as long as there are fewer than 26 columns. This won't do `AA, AB`, but that would be possible with more code if you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, appreciate it a lot! 

I understand my previous code more clearly now. However, I do not follow you exactly with the last bit. What is the context of c['SOME INDEX HERE'] in this code? I want to be able to select every single CSV data point as its own variable in following action steps. What would you advise to replace SOME INDEX HERE with?

Comment: To clarify further -- the desired output is as follows:

{ A1 : data A1, A2 : data A2, ... }

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are using splitlines() which if your data is something along the lines of "data,data,data,...,/ndata,data,data" with the /n being a line break then splitlines() will break that into two strings rather than separating each data point. If you add an additional loop during the CSV reading you could isolate those data points. So after 'for line in csv.read..." add a second, nested, for loop: "for data in line: result.append(data)". Hopefully that is clear. I can submit as a full answer with examples if needed.